# Unable to use GPU in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I want to use GPU & Anaconda environment on Linux.
I'm supposed to have adapted the versions of each module, but it doesn't work.
Cuda and cuDNN are installed by using conda.
The versions of each module and driver are listed below:

・GPU：RTX 2070 SUPEER
・OS：Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia ( Ubuntu 18.04 )
・Nvidia-driver：435.21

```
# conda list tensorflow
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py37h6c5654b_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                h0d30ee6_0

# conda list cudnn
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0

# conda list cudatoolkit
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0
```

I can see the GPU by entering the following command

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

When I run the training script, I get the following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[node conv1d_3/convolution ......
```

How do I get it to work correctly?

Comment: How did you install `cudnn`? This may have something to do with incompatibility between versions and the existing packages on your system. If possible, please describe how did you install `tensorflow` GPU version.

Comment: Thank your for replying!
I installed tensorflow/cuda/cudnn with the following command `conda install tensorflow=2.1.0=gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0`.

Comment: Would you like to work with version `tensorflow=2.1.0` specifically OR you simply want it to run? Could you try to create a new environment (e.g., `conda create --name newENV python=3.7`, I expect you use `python3`) and try `conda install tensorflow-gpu`, let me know if `tensorflow` is able to recognize the GPU or not.

Comment: I simply want it to run.  When I tried it the way you taught me, the GPU shows up with the following command ('device_lib.list_local_devices()'), but I get the same error when I run the script. Does installing keras-gpu or scikit-learn have a negative effect?

Comment: To debug the issue, I highly recommend that you:
1. Create a new conda environment
2. Perform a fresh installation of `conda install tensorflow-gpu`
3. Run this to test: `tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")`

if the error stills occurs, I think there is some problem with your packages outside `conda`.

Comment: I ran `tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")` and, I get the following log, which seems to be fine.
`pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5`
`coreClock: 1.77GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s`
`[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`

Comment: Congratz! it works. Would you like me to write the debugging process in `answer` section? I would appreciate if you consider it as an answer,

Comment: But I can't run the training script yet. :,-( I get the following error. `Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[node model/conv1d_2/conv1d .......` Could you tell me a little more about it?

Comment: Can you try [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25160#issuecomment-568505081)

Comment: Wow! It finally worked! Most comfortable! Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear. I’ll answer it in the section below. Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** lack of hardware resource.

**Workaround:**
Fresh installed TF 2.0 and ran a simple Minst tutorial, it was alright, opened another notebook, tried to run and encountered this issue.

I exited all notebooks and restarted Jupyter and open only one notebook, ran it successfully. Issue seems to be either memory or running more than one notebook on GPU

More reading [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25160#issuecomment-568505081).